# phpunit installed via composer, tell phing to use that

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, phing

I can't seem to get Phing to use my PHPUnit installed through composer (in a project local `bin/` directory). As last resort if I tell Phing to use my phpunit executable as-if it a PHAR file using `<phpunit pharlocation="${basedir}/bin/phpunit" />`

But that also fails with:

```
Project > phpunit:

#!/usr/bin/env php
PHPUnit 4.8.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

unrecognized option -- f
```

I'd rather not tamper with my PATH because other developers should be able to run the phing phpunit-target without any big hassle. Also a globally installed phpunit is not something I'd want, because I do not want version differences between developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you already tried the Phing Autoload Task ?

https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/AutoloaderTask.html

I'm using it this way:

Comment: A pity you didn't complete your answer with your own example. In my case, adding a trivial `<autoloader />` was enough. This is better than my answer in the case phing is installed locally. In the case that phing itself is installed as a Composer dependency, this step would not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Turning your `PhpunitTask` into an`ExecTask` should help:

```
<target name="phpunit">
    <exec logoutput="true" checkreturn="true" dir="${basedir}" command="bin/phpunit" />
</target>
```

For reference, see https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/ExecTask.html.

Answer (score 0):

Phing uses your project local libraries, including PHPUnit libraries, you should not have to explicitly mention the `bin/phpunit` executable.

How phing knows to look at project local dependencies is unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it autoloading composer/autoload.php file

```
<project name="name" default="build">
  <autoloader autoloaderpath="${baseDir}/vendor/autoload.php"/>

  <target name="tests">
        <phpunit bootstrap="${testsDir}/bootstrap.php" >
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
            <batchtest>
                <fileset dir="${testsDir}">
                    <include name="**/*Test*.php"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </phpunit>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, still getting `PHPUnitTask requires PHPUnit to be installed`